# RRD Tool - confusing start time

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I'm setting up a rrd database to store sensor data for 3 days in 12hr intervalls (43200s) = 6 row in RRA.

> rrdtool create test.rrd --step 43200 --start 1562429286 DS:temp:GAUGE:86400:U:U RRA:AVERAGE:0:1:6

The databases starting time is **1562429286** (**06.07.2019 - 18:08:06**).

When I dump the database:

> rrdtool dump test.rrd

it says (output trimmed for clarity):

> 2019-07-04 02:00:00 CEST / 1562198400 NaN
>
> 2019-07-04 14:00:00 CEST / 1562241600 NaN
>
> 2019-07-05 02:00:00 CEST / 1562284800 NaN
>
> 2019-07-05 14:00:00 CEST / 1562328000 NaN
>
> 2019-07-06 02:00:00 CEST / 1562371200 NaN
>
> 2019-07-06 **14:00:00** CEST / **1562414400** NaN

I expected rrdtool to give the next nearest timestamp ( 6.7.19 18:00 ) as the  last entry ("starting point") instead. So why is it at 14:00 ?
At first this explanation ([How to create a rrd file with a specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456062/how-to-create-a-rrd-file-with-a-specific-time)) made perfect sense for the small intervall of 5m to me. But in my case I cannot get behind the logic if the intervall is bigger (12h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the RRA buckets are always normalised to be aligned to the GMT (UCT) timezone.  It is not visible if you are using a cdp (consolodated data point) width of an hour or less; but in your case, your cdp are 12 hours in width.  Your timezone means that these are offset by 2 hours from UCT zero resulting in apparent boundaries of 02 and 14 local time (if you were in London then you'd be seeing 0 and 12 as expected).

This effect is much more noticeable when you are using 1-day rollups and are located in somewhere like New Zealand, when you'll see the CDP boundary appearing at noon rather than at midnight.

It is not currently possible to specify a different timezone to use as a base for the RRA buckets (this would make the data nonportable) though I believe it has been on the RRDTool feature request list for a number of years.